Which entries in aux file are read by bib2gls?
I think I know the answer for bibtex:
\bibcite, \bibstyle, \bibdata and @input commands.
For bib2gls not so clear to me.
I ask because I am working on a specialized build tool
and I am interested in rerun check.
Firstly: how can I find out whether bib2gls must be called at all?
Again for bibtex seems to be simple: if and only if bibdata present.
Secondly: When to rerun... bibtex maybe not at all,
but bib2gls? well... Does bib2gls read aux files of included TEX files??
I would appreciate if glossaries-extra would log some hint whether to run bib2gls... But nothing found..
EDIT: bibtex reads \citation not \bibcite,
thanks @egreg.

BibTeX doesn't use \bibcite, but \citation.

@egreg you are right: these entries hide in the aux files of included tex files in my case. I corrected...

seems as if \bibcite is added by the latex engine after run of bibtex.

Yes, of course. But BibTeX still ignores it.
